# Accessing data acroos 2 farms

Tags: credentials, multiple-farms

So, heres my issue. There are 2 farms. The data I need is from the other farms mysite. Im using this code and the web service userProfileService to try and get the data. At the quickLinkData part,Line #3, it craps out and says:

SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to
perform an unauthorized operation.

```
string currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.ToString();
userProfileService.UseDefaultCredentials = true; 
QuickLinkData[] links = userProfileService.GetUserLinks(currentUser);
```

So any tips or advice?

Comment: Do you want to access user profile service of farm2 or you need to sync both farms user profile service?

Comment: I want to access the data.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this problem recently and the problem is that the account I'm using to call the User Profile Service is not part of the Administrator group of the User Profile Service Application in other farm. After adding the user to that group and set it's permission to Manage Profiles, I no longer encounter the error. Hope this works for you.

Comment: thanks, how would you do that? I'm sorry but I usually just code. Not too familiar with sharepoint. I've gotten into the central administration. Now im lost

Comment: didnt work, thanks though